# How to define a custom slot type for flight codes in Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I want to create a german custom slot type for flight codes. A flight code consists of a short abbreviation of the airline, e.g.

```
EZY, DLH, AFR, ABY, AAL, RYR, DAL, ...
```

and a 3 to 5 digit number, e.g.

```
352, 5832, 84544, ...
```

so the slot type examples should read something like this:

```
EZY582, AFR5583, RYR19, DAL2912, ...
```

So how what would be the best option for me to create such a slot type? Remember, I use the german language.

First, I tried using two different slot types for the carrier code and the flight number:

```
FLIGHT_CODE and AMAZON.NUMBER
```

There were a lot of issues, where the model would only recognise the FLIGHT_CODE even if the speech prompt explicitly also asks for both of these slot types at once.

Second, I tried defining the slot type with phonetically correct values:

```
"e. z. y. drei vier acht"
```

but the "e. z. y." won't get matched correctly. Is there a best practice to get such combined types? Especially by including abbreviations like "E. Z. Y.", which will get pronounced very differently in german? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but in case someone has the same issue this is how I solved it. I didn't find a suitable way to specify a slot for the flight code itself. However, you could prompt for the name of the airline and the 3 to 5 digit number. Something like this in the utterance:

`{airline_name} {flight_number}`

There is a built-in slot type called `AMAZON.Airline`. So the type for `airline_name` will be `AMAZON.AIRLINE` and `AMAZON.NUMBER` for the `number`. The built-in type can be extended for resolutions and validation to work on. You can follow this guide: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#h2_extend_types

That way you can assign an ID for each airline and synonyms:

```
Slot types: AMAZON.AIRLINE

Value | ID | Synonyms 
American Airlines | AA | American
LATAM Airlines | LA | LAN, LATAM
...
```

That way you will have access to resolutions field in the JSON and you can obtain the airline id. You can also add a validation to compare the fields from the extended type:

```
"dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "FlightIntent",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "airline_name",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Airline",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": false,
                            "prompts": {},
                            "validations": [
                                {
                                    "type": "hasEntityResolutionMatch",
                                    "prompt": "Slot.Validation.1129359808444.140964634934.1466054813690"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
...
"prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Slot.Validation.1129359808444.140964634934.1466054813690",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Please tell me the name of the airline followed by the number"
                    }
                ]
            }
```